# Formal methods for identifying characteristics of a Cluster

Tags: clustering, predictive-models

I have a data-set of about 100 columns (predictors). To this I have appended a categorical column, with three discrete levels, 1-3. These levels are derived by grouping predictions from a model (fitted on this dataset). I want to know if there are any formal way to identify what set of characteristics can describe level 1 and so on. For example, are there methods that can tell me that records with Age >= 30 and Gender Male are representative of level 1?

Comment: A decision true could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for methods in [association rule mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning).  The essential idea in association rule mining is to find relationships between variables, especially frequently-occurring sets.  For example, if age>30 and male frequently implies that a user is in level 1, a frequent-pattern miner such as [FP-tree](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.4436) might be good at finding such a pattern.

Note that this is assuming you are interested in finding *many* such patterns.  If you only need the most relevant pattern you can simply train a [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) to predict the classification given the input variables, and the top few levels should be a pretty good explanation of why things end up in various categories.

Comment: I agree with @Scott

However, there is no guarantee that you will get non overlapping patterns